# How to the result set form the below table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1 contains certain set of data's. I need to get the following result set form the Table 1

Table1

```
Id  Desc          ParentId
1   Cloths            0
2   Mens              1
3   Womens            1
4   T-Shirt_M         2
5   Casual Shirts_M   2
6   T-Shirt_F         3
7   Education         8
```

If I pass a parameter as "Casual Shirts_M" I should get the below result set.

Result Set

```
Id  Desc          ParentId
1   Cloths            0
2   Mens              1
5   Casual Shirts_M   2
```

Comment: You would use a recursive cte for this. There literally thousands and thousands of examples of how to do this all over the place.

Comment: I note that ID 7 has a parent ID of 8, however ID 8 doesn't exist (I assume 0 means no parent). What would you expect here? Should data have no parent? This implies that you don't have a (foreign key) constraint.

Comment: @Larnu it looks to me like its a hierarchical structure with the parent ID being a foreign key to the ID in the same table

Comment: There's still no `8`, nor is there a `0`.  If this was a foreign key constraint then `NULL` would mean no parent...?

Comment: I have to agree with @Larnu and Richard. There either is no Foreign key here or the sample data is incomplete. I hope the latter because having no foreign key is really bad design

Comment: The point, @WhatsThePoint , is that in a hierarchy the Parent ID **must** exist or be *`NULL`* (when the row has no Parent). If it has a parent that doesn't exist, then that record is orphaned, and can next be reached in the hierarchy tree.

Comment: you should flag this and ask for it to be migrated to [dba.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, there are plenty of Recursive Common Table Expressions examples for this, here's another one

```
DECLARE @Desc NVARCHAR(50) = 'Casual Shirts_M'
;WITH cteX
AS
(   SELECT
        B.Id, B.[DESC], B.ParentId
    FROM
        Table1 b
    WHERE
        B.[Desc] = @Desc
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        E.Id, E.[DESC], E.ParentId
    FROM
        Table1  E
    INNER JOIN
        cteX r ON e.Id = r.ParentId
)
SELECT * FROM cteX ORDER BY ID ASC
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e33c/2) provided by @WhatsThePoint

Answer (score 0):

The question comes under the concept of Building hierarchy using Recursive CTE:

```
 CREATE TABLE cloths 
  ( 
     id       INT, 
     descr    VARCHAR(100), 
     parentid INT 
  ); 


insert into cloths values (1,'Cloths',0);
insert into cloths values (2,'Mens',1);
insert into cloths values (3,'Womens',1);
insert into cloths values (4,'T-Shirt_M',2);
insert into cloths values (5,'Casual Shirts_M',2);
insert into cloths values (6,'T-Shirt_F',3);
insert into cloths values (7,'Education',8);


DECLARE @variety VARCHAR(100) = 'Casual Shirts_M'; 

WITH 
cte1 (id, descr, parentid) 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   cloths 
         WHERE  descr = @variety 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT c.id, 
                c.descr, 
                c.parentid 
         FROM   cloths c 
                INNER JOIN cte1 r 
                        ON c.id = r.parentid) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte1 
ORDER  BY parentid ASC;
```